# Is a Java class variable a reference to a class object?

Tags: java, class, object, reference

I know such question has been asked before but I couldn't find a satisfactory answer.
Assume a java class  :

```
class Foo{
    public int k;
    Foo(int a){
         k=a;
    } 
}
class My{
    public static void main(String args[]){
        Foo obj = new Foo(5);//1
        obj=new Foo(8); //2
    }
}
```

I want to know if obj can be assumed to be a reference to a foo type of an object. As per my understanding in line 1 JVM makes a new foo type of object and passes it reference to obj but in line 2 we are able to over ride the value of obj with a new object.

So my question is if obj is a reference then should'nt it only point to one object ( deriving this definition from c++ , reference are like constant pointers).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`obj` is a reference to the object of type `foo` , your understanding is correct. In line 1 , JVM creates a new instance (ojbect) of type `foo` (new memory is allocated in the heap) , and `obj` now stores the reference to that memory location, lets assume that memory location is `1001` . So after line one -

```
obj -> 1001
```

After line 2 , JVM creates a new object of same type `foo` (that is completely new memory is allocated in heap) , lets say this time `2001` , is the memory allocated to the new object, now after line 2 , the reference of `obj` is updated and changed from `1001` to`2001`.

```
obj -> 2001
```

After line 2, the object allocated in memory location`1001` does not have any reference in the code, so eventually JVM would garbage collect that memory, meaning, it would free the memory up for future allocation to other objects.

References in Java are not like  C++ , they are not constant pointers, you can think of them as normal `pointers` from c++ , you can change the memory location that it refers/points to at any time, given the limitation, that it has to be a memory location of same type , that is the object has to be of same type (`foo`)

Comment: just one  more thing , if i pass the obj to a function and that function does some changes to it , will those changes be reflected in the main function scope too  ?

Comment: Yes, just like c++ , when you pass pointers to c++ function, and make any change inside the function to the memory location pointed to by the pointer, it reflects in the other functions as well (this being called `call by reference`) , its the same for java objects, when you pass java objects to functions, they are passed by `reference` , any change inside the object would be reflected. But please note, like in the case of C++ , if you directly change the complete object itself, lets say a line like `argument = new Foo(10)` , they won't be reflected, same as c++

Answer (score 1):

You understanding is perfectly correct. obj now points to the second foo object. In this case foo(5) is not referred by any object and will be garbage collected by JVM.

Comment: in second part i asked if reference by definition are like constant pointers ( c++) then how can its value be chanced after initialisation ?

Comment: Why do you think they are constant pointers? Nopes they are not constant pointers.

Answer (score 1):

`Foo obj` creates a `reference variable` in Java which can hold the reference to an object of that class.

`new Foo();` statement actually creates an object. As many times as you write `new Foo();` a new object will be created.

> if obj is a reference then should'nt it only point to one object

No it is not the case. It is not any kind of limitation that one reference variable can only point to one object only. It can point to any object.

I will say it is similar to the following,

```
int a = 10;
a = 15;
```

And as other users have already posted, an object in Java, which has no reference variable pointing to it, can be Garbage Collected.

Answer (score 0):

```
Foo obj = new Foo(5);//1
```

**Declaration +Instantiation +Initialization**

```
obj = new foo(8);
```

**Instantiation +Initialization**

I prints obj in your program before and after 'obj = new foo(8);' line

```
foo obj = new foo(5);// 1
System.out.println("Before:" + obj);
obj = new foo(8); // 2
System.out.println("After:" + obj);
```

and the output is

```
Before:com.test.foo@1db9742
After:com.test.foo@106d69c
```

You can easily understand from this output that  `new foo(8);` statement actually creates a new object.

For more see Java docs [Creating Objects](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/objectcreation.html)